# Simple console application compiled with Intel C++ Compiler 2019.4 does not run on Ryzen processor

Tags: c++, x86, intel, icc, amd-processor

The simple program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf( "Hello, world!\n" );
}
```

when compiled with Intel C++ Compiler 2019.4 with the following switches:
`/O3 /Qunroll /Qunroll-aggressive /QxSSE3 /QaxCORE-AVX2` refuses to run on Ryzen 3 1200 processor running Windows 10.

The error I get on the console is the list of processor features required to run the application. All of these features are available on Ryzen processor (SSE3, AVX2, CMOV, FXSAVE, etc) yet the application does not run.

The full run-time library error for this simple program reads as follows:

> `Please verify that both the operating system and the processor support Intel(R) X87, CMOV, MMX, FXSAVE, SSE, SSE2 and SSE3 instructions.`

This is just a bare minimum example, I of course have a lot more complex application on my mind, but it does not run either.

The only workaround is to use `/O3 /Qunroll /Qunroll-aggressive /QxSSE2` switches, but that effectively disables AVX2 auto-dispatch and SSE3 instructions.

Is there a workaround for this issue possible?

Comment: Which instruction actually faults?  Run your program under a debugger.  I think Ryzen has everything that Haswell does, but maybe I'm forgetting something.  (Core-AVX2 means "haswell", I think.  Modern ICC lets you use `-march=haswell` just like GCC)

Comment: It's not an instruction that fails, this error is displayed by Intel's own run-time library.

Comment: Even though those instruction sets are available compiler-emitted code that verifies their availability may not necessary recognize their presence on non-intel CPUs.

Comment: This is not true, when I build a DLL with the same switches, no error happens.

Comment: Can you quote the exact error message in your question?  Anyway, maybe you need to just enable specific instruction sets.  Maybe telling ICC to build for "core-avx2" makes it check for an actual Intel CPU, but maybe `-mavx2 -mfma -mbmi -mbmi2 -mpopcnt` would just enable those extensions but not tell ICC that you were building specifically for an Intel CPU.  It sounds like ICC is purposely stopping your application from running on AMD CPUs, and I'm guessing that's because of `/QaxCORE-AVX2`, but I don't use ICC.  Another option would be to use clang.

Comment: I need an auto-dispatch code for backwards compatibility, and the only option here is to use /Qax. The auto-dispatch works perfectly, on Intel CPUs.

Comment: More details: if I use `/QxSSE3` without `/QaxCORE-AVX2` the application does not start either.

Comment: Clang does not support auto-dispatch and its AVX2 optimizer lags behind Intel's a lot. I need to ship software that works on antique Core 2 Duo processors, thousands of users. I can't just compile for AVX2 exclusively, it won't work.

Comment: Ah I see, I was assuming `QaxCORE-AVX2` was like `-march=core-avx2`, my mistake.  GCC has a similar function multiversioning with auto dispatching feature, ifunc.  But probably not as good as ICC's.   And like clang, it's not as good at auto-vectorizing some loops, and can't do it at all for search loops (where the trip-count isn't known before the first iteration).  With profile-guided optimization it's pretty good a lot of the time.  But if Intel is intentionally breaking your program for AMD CPUs, I suggest contacting Intel support about it.

Comment: I'm waiting 3 days already for my similar message to pass their moderation on their official support forum.

Comment: GCC is a pain to use on Windows, no production-ready packages available to my knowledge, mingw tends to be buggy.

Comment: No anti-viral software is installed on my Ryzen processor. The applications I ship do not work on other users' AMD computers as well.

Comment: You might want to read section 13.7 (CPU dispatching in Intel compiler) of [Agner Fog's optimization guide](https://www.agner.org/optimize/optimizing_cpp.pdf). He has some information on the Intel CPU dispatcher and some possible workarounds (and code) that might be relevant here.

Comment: Thanks! While this does not solve an original issue, calling the `__intel_cpu_features_init_x()` explicitly proved to be very beneficial when running on Ryzen processor. Hate Intel after that...

Answer (score 2):

Even though those instruction sets are available compiler-emitted code that verifies their availability may not necessary recognize their presence on non-intel CPUs. [Documentation](https://software.intel.com/en-us/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-x-qx) explicitly states that options like `CORE-AVX2` may work only for Intel processors:

> **CORE-AVX2** May generate Intel® Advanced Vector Extensions 2 (Intel® AVX2), Intel® AVX, SSE4.2, SSE4.1, SSE3, SSE2, SSE, and SSSE3 instructions for Intel® processors. Optimizes for Intel® processors that support Intel® AVX2 instructions.

(remarks)

> Intel does not guarantee the availability, functionality, or effectiveness of any optimization on microprocessors not manufactured by Intel.

Comment: The CPUID feature flags for detecting these extensions are the same across all x86 CPUs.  I'm almost certain that making it not work on AMD is an intentional choice by Intel that takes extra code to check for AMD CPUs.  Not that they "didn't bother adding AMD support", they specifically added "AMD anti-support" code to their detection library.  But yes, this does explain the situation.

Comment: Note that /Qax is `auto-dispatch` feature, it is optional. I do not see even a theoretic problem, if it's not supported, skip it, why stop the application with run-time library error?

Comment: I've received a reply from Intel: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/optimization-notice#opt-en It tells "does not optimize to the same degree". But the problem is that application does not run at all on Ryzen processor.

Answer (score -3):

Intel and Ryzen is not same for compilation, for example, Intel compile with one architecture to his processor and Ryzen to his, if you compile into Intel and execute on Ryzen, what will be happen ?

Comment: This is irrelevant. I need to build a shipping commercial program, and it simply refuses to work on Ryzen processors.

Comment: Try compile on ryzen